# PuLP termination criterium: fracgap (COIN-CMD)

Tags: python, excel, linear-programming, solver, pulp

I am running an optimization problem that is unable to find the optimal solution (within 10 minutes). I think that is caused by the fact that very tiny improvements keep getting found. I want to cut this proces short, so as not to spend too much time on too little improvements.

I am using the COIN-CMD class (via SolverStudio in Excel):

```
class pulp.solvers.COIN_CMD(path=None, keepFiles=0, mip=1, msg=0, cuts=None, presolve=None, dual=None, strong=None, options=[], fracGap=None, maxSeconds=None, threads=None)
```

One possibility is to set a time limit, but the downside of this is that I do not know how large the improvements of the solution are. This should therefore be a final go-to strategy.

**Is there an alternative method to terminate the solving process, for example, when a sufficiently good solution is found?** Alternatively, is there an place where the parameters and their workings are nicely documented? I notice that https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/index.html is a little meager in that regard.

Comment: Your mentioned alternative is a bit scary, as the value of one improvement does not say anything about further improvements in general (especially for MIPs). This would mean, that you stop before the solver can easily find better solutions, or you would need to make this more complex (n_non_improvements, running-average and co). I don't think this kind of behaviour is supported by most solvers (incl. commercial ones). I'm afraid you have to stick to TimeLimit/maxSeconds and MIPGap/fracGap (relative or absolute). side-note: if you are doing research: you can obtain academic licenses for Gurobi

Comment: @sascha, Thank you for your quick reply. Do you know where I can read up on MIPGaps and fracgaps?

Comment: As pulp is just passing these options to CBC, you should start with CBC's docs. They are not that great, but some stuff you can learn from [here for example](https://www.coin-or.org/Cbc/cbcuserguide.html). Maybe you need to dig through pulp's sources too to learn how this mapping is done.

Comment: @sascha thank you so much. I'll definitely have a look at it. I have rephrased the question just asking for alternatives to a time limit. If you are willing to answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: It's not quite obvious what kind of task you are approaching. But i often combine time-limit and mip-gaps. Solver will end when mip-gap is reached or when time-limit is reached. Of course it's necessary then to read out the status. You may even read out the obtained mip-gap to further decide on what you do with this run (reject, redo with different seed and co.). Sadly i can't give much info about pulp and cbc as i'm more of an gurobi-user (which you could use for university work for free). time-limit and frac-gap should both work, although i' not sure how to read out additional status-info

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found three different ways to specify gaps in CBC (programmed in C++) [here](https://www.coin-or.org/Cbc/cbcuserguide.html):

```
bool setAllowableGap(double value)
bool setAllowablePercentageGap(double value)
bool setAllowableFractionGap(double value)
```

I am guessing that with `setAllowableGap` you set an absolute value, and whenever the gap between the best known solution and the possbile best solution is smaller than that value the solving process will terminate. 
With `setAllowablePercentageGap` the gap should be smaller than the specified percentage (say, 5%), and the with `setAllowableFractionGap` it seems that the gap should smaller than a fraction (say, 0.05). I am not sure what the possible best solution would be, or how it would be calculated, though. It would be great if someone could expand on this.

In PuLP, you can only specify the `fracgap` parameter.

Comment: This is inside CBC. You probably want something you can specify in `pulp`. Unless your objective is close to zero (in which case a relative gap is not as useful), just use `fracGap=0.05` or whatever gap tolerance you want.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Yes thank you. I've added it in my answer. I am interested how to specify a gap if the solution is indeed around 0.

Comment: Either do some programming and add a `absgap` option to PulP, or artificially make the objective nonzero (add a term).